# Google news Rss character encoding issue in iOS

Tags: ios, character-encoding, rss, google-news

I created simple iOS app which get information from Google news rss feed (Different language feeds) and display feeds in tableview. App is already in live. Few week before Google done some changes!, after that content coming from google news rss is strange, looks like below image. I don't what type of encoding google doing.

Please help. [Sample Rss link](http://news.google.co.in/news?cf=all&ned=ta_in&hl=ta&output=rss&num=40)

[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZN70.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The Google News Feed is UTF-8, so the problem happens in your app. Are you sure you're not interpreting the text using another encoding?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Thanks for your answer. Currently i'm doing UTF-8 encoding for incoming response. Now everything works fine.